# OPOS ADK For NET is not working on serial port

Tags: opos, pos-for-.net

I installed Microsoft POS for .NET 1.14.1 and installed the EPSON OPOS ADK for .NET. I used the OPOS ADK setup and checked "USB" and "Serial" check boxes and created 2 configurations; one for the USB and one for the Serial Port. In the "Serial" setup, I know I have placed the right values since those values came from the printer itself. Using the USB port, I don't get any problems but when I transfer the printer's connection to serial port and using the "CheckHealth", I get this message

```
ErrorCode: 111
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
Message: It is not Initialized
```

I know that my serial cable is working because I have tested it on other devices.

Comment: Please try to find if it is written in any of the ADK documents. What is valid probably depends on your hardware configuration. You wouldn't be able to arbitrarily switch between both interfaces with one hardware configuration at a given time. Please try changing the settings with the tools provided by EPSON.

Comment: @kunif The configuration is from the printer itself. I printed the configuration values like BaudRate, Parity, Bits, etc. from the printer by pressing the "feed" button and then powering it on. The OPOS ADK has a setup interface where you can create 2 modes of connection (even 3) USB, Serial, Ethernet, etc. Each of this setup has different configurations. So I think this is the purpose of that multiple instances. You can change what to used depending on your connection. The tools I am using were from EPSON itself.

Comment: Many printers, support two logical interface types. One is the USBPRINT interface and the other is the vendor specific (this is USB serial) interface. And after changing it, you also need to install the corresponding device driver. OPOS can only be used in vendor-specific mode, and Advanced Printer Driver can only be used in USBPRINT mode, right? After all, what you are trying to do and the problem is occurring should be presented with detailed information such as the program source code, device settings, and corresponding registries, rather than a short sentence.

Comment: The Advanced Printer Driver can be used in USB, Serial And Parallel print. All using the same driver. As for if OPOS can only be used in vendor-specifc mode, well I am using the TM-T82II from EPSON so I think the ADK should be able to drive or detect it atleast. But it is not in my case. For the program source code, I am not creating the program yet, I am just using the HealthCheck that came with the OPOS ADK. From that alone, I cannot make the device print.

Comment: So maybe you're misconfiguring something, doing it the wrong way, or trying to do several things at the same time? If you don't describe in detail what you did and how you did it in such a way that other people can reproduce it, it will be difficult to get accurate advice and answers.